# API.AI "Invalid Argument" error when trying to update integration with Actions on Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

2 days ago the integration between Google home and API.AI agent worked perfectly. Since yesterday, when the API.AI was updated to include Google Assistant integration instead of Google Home, i had to do some extra steps on Action on Google console to make that integration work again.

But when i click on "Fulfillment" on API.AI menu, then "Google Assistant", i get the following screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gPPF.png)

But when i click on "update" or "test" i get the following error message: "Request contains and invalid argument".

How can i solve this?

Comment: You said that you had to do "some extra steps". Can you elaborate?

Comment: Well on Tuesday before Google I/O the integration of the API.AI agent was with Google Home, not Google Assistant, and the integration consisted in giving basic Google Authorization with a prompt. Now the integration with Google Assistant first asked me to create a project on the Actions On Google console with some basic informations about the agent and its invocation name.

Comment: I solved it by creating/replicating the API.AI agent from scratch. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I too had to recreate with a brand new agent.  Here's the steps I took that may help others who venture down this path...

1. Create a new **Actions on Google** project from the console:  [Actions on Google console](https://console.actions.google.com/)
2. Create a zip file of just your intents and entities folders.  They need to be in the top level of the zip file.  (`agent.json` seems to be the one file that kept blowing up my agent after Google updated everything)
3. Create a new Agent in **API.ai** as  you normally would
4. Save and finish up the "Actions on Google" console setup for the new project
5. Go back to API.ai and click on "**Integrations**" and "**Actions on Google**".  This will allow you to click on "**Update**" and hopefully test the generic beginning of the agent successfully.
6. Finally, once you have tested the generic agent, import the zip file you created earlier and all "**should**" work fine.  You'll have to update your fulfillment server if using one, etc.

The above works as of the morning of May 23, 2017.  Good luck!